# Passing a HttpServletRequest Object as a Parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

In general, I need to upload a large file via an html form calling a servlet, and then manipulate that file with a heavy algorithm and return a xml document as a response. 
This whole process takes a lot of time, so in order to avoid the browser timeout connection, I  have decided to create an object (extending `Thread`) that will perform the time consuming process (uploading the file and manipulate it) in a different thread and that will be able to indicate the progress of the process. To do that, I need to pass the `HttpServletRequest` request as an argument to the object.
When I tried to parse the request parameter (I am using apache commons FileUpload), I got the following exception:

```
"the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null" .
```

Is it possible to pass a `HttpServletRequest` object to an object extending Thread? if so, what is the correct practice of safely doing it?

Comment: does your html form contain the enctype attribute with a value `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Yes. I can do it easily in the doPost method, the problem is when I pass the request as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't. When the request object is used in the thread, the request may no longer be valid, and Tomcat might have cleaned it (hence your exception) (of course, assuming your form is indeed a `enctype="multipart/form-data"`)

So in order to handle this properly, extract the data from the request and pass it to the new thread. Thus you won't depend on the request object - only on its contents.

Note that Servlet 3.0 adds an option for asynchronous server-side processing which seems to be a good option for you - [check it out](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the asynchronous server-side processing, I will look into it. I wanted to prevent the browser from waiting until I am done extracting the file from the request (as I do now in the doPost method), so I thought of doing it in a different thread. So is it impossible to pass the request as an argument?

Comment: simply getting the data from it shouldn't be expensive, so get the data and pass it to the thread instead.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about "the request may no longer be valid"?  Dang, this answer is several years old, probably no one will see this comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting indicates that the form on the client side may not be set up properly. Make sure that your form is defines like this:

```
   <FORM action="YOUR_SERVLET"
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
   method="post">
```

Comment: It does. I am doing it easily in the doPost method, the problem is when I pass the request as a parameter.